# Не работает свойство z-index для блока

Tags: css, вёрстка, z-index, slick.js

Первый раз использовал слайдер slick, возникла проблема с отображением блока item-sq. Указываю любое значение z-index, блок отображается не так как нужно. В чем может быть проблема?
На картинке стрелками указан тот самый блок и то как он должен отображаться.
[image: Как должно быть]
[Ссылка на страницу](http://qosmo7.github.io)

```css
.clients-item {
  width: 535px;
  height: 279.5px;
  padding: 85px 45px 0 45px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}

.clients-item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 27px 0px rgba(20, 20, 21, 0.09);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.item-sq {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 217px;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<article class="clients">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1><span>clients</span> said</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ultrices dictum porttitor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="clients-item">
          <div class="item-sq"></div>
          <p>"This was my first time renting from car rental. The service rep help me find the best rental to suit my needs. I will definitely rent with this company again"</p>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h6><span>kita say,</span>HK director1</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="clients-item">
          <div class="item-sq"></div>
          <p>"This was my first time renting from car rental. The service rep help me find the best rental to suit my needs. I will definitely rent with this company again"</p>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h6><span>kita say,</span>HK director2</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="clients-item">
          <div class="item-sq"></div>
          <p>"This was my first time renting from car rental. The service rep help me find the best rental to suit my needs. I will definitely rent with this company again"</p>
          <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <h6><span>kita say,</span>HK director3</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте родительскому елементу задать position: relative и z-index меньше чем у нужного елемента.
А что бы круги не обрезались из за свойства overflow: hidded у slick контейнера задайте ему padding-top

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2rem auto 0;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle--behind {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="circle"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
<div class="circle circle--behind"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не работает z-index - то либо у одного из связующих элементов нужно поменять position на relative или absolute. Либо почистить кэш (иногда бывает, что некоторые изменения не отображаются сразу)